# To stay the feet of every passer-by

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry

What does ***To stay the feet*** mean in the verse below

> And hear the others who with cymbals try
> **To stay the feet** of every passer-by:
>    The market-men along the darkling lane
> Are crying up their wares.—Oh! let them cry.

Source: *[The Luzumiyat of Abu’l-Ala, IV](https://poets.org/poem/luzumiyat-abul-ala-iv)* by Al-Ma‘arri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb "stay", when used with an object, means to prevent {something} from moving, or to "stop {something}".  It is rather formal or literary.

So the band tries to stop people's feet, that is stop them from walking away. That is the band tries to get them to stop and listen to the music.

Comment: Yes, people used to say 'Stay your hand!' I still do sometimes.